# iOS: Can one view see objects created in another

Tags: objective-c, ios

G'day all,

I have been reading about protocols and delegates for passing data between controllers.

Suppose ViewControllerA creates an instance on an object:

```
myObject = [[anObject alloc]init];
[myObject setProperty: value];
```

How does ViewControllerB access myObject's property?  How does ViewControllerB become aware of objects created by ViewControllerA?

Thanks,

Comment: ViewControllerB could be a delegate of ViewControllerA. That way ViewControllerA could pass messages to ViewControllerB when objects are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to let who ever interested to know about the new object.
Usually this is done in the model layer, for example I have a `Person` object.
Define a "new person created notification" in the `Person` .h file

```
extern NSString *const NewPersonCreatedNotification;
```

in the .m file

```
NSString *const NewPersonCreatedNotification = @"NewPersonCreatedNotification";
```

When a person is created (in the init method) post the notification

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NewPersonCreatedNotification
                                                        object:self
                                                      userInfo:nil];
```

Then whoever wants to know about new persons created will need to observe this notifications  , for example ViewControllerA wants to know, so in it's init method I do:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(handleNewPersonCreatedNotification:)
                                                     name:NewPersonCreatedNotification
                                                   object:nil];    
    }
    return self;
}  


- (void)handleNewPersonCreatedNotification:(NSNotification *)not
{
    // get the new Person object  
    Person *newPerson = [not object];  

    // do something with it...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If B comes after A (i.e. they are hierarchical) you can just pass the object to B (after creating it or in `prepareForSegue`:

```
bController.objectProperty = myObject;
```

If both are active for the user at the same time (say via a tab bar), you could use notifications. This is different from delegates in that the relationship is looser - the sending object does not have to know anything about the receiving object.

```
// in A
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
   postNotificationName:ObjectChangedNOtificationName 
   object:self
   userInfo:dictionaryWithObject];
// in B
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
   selector:@selector(objectChanged:) 
   name:ObjectChangedNOtificationName 
   object:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks Mundi.  I'll have a look at notifications.